# Norms of orthogonal subspaces

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality, projection

Let V be a finite dimensional real inner product space and U, W subspaces of
V such that U is orthogonal to W. Show that for any $v ∈ V$
$$||v||^2 ≥ ||proj U (v)||^2 + ||projW (v)||^2$$

Hello guys. I am trying to prove this. I am doing 3 cases. First one is v is in span of orthogonal basis of U. Second one is that v is in span of orthogonal basis of W. These two case is clear. But in the final case, when v is not element of span of these two orthogonal bases, i could not find a way to prove it.

Comment: Observe that $U+W$ is not necessarily $V$. That is the reason for the $\le$ sign..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your two cases into one by producing the orthogonal complement of $U \oplus W$ inside $V$.

Indeed, if $V$ is the orthogonal direct sum $U_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_n$, then it is generally true for $ v = u_1 + \cdots + u_n$, that

$$\|v\|^2 = \|u_1\|^2 + \cdots \|u_n\|^2.$$

Apply this principle to your case, with $V = U \oplus W \oplus [U \oplus W]^{\perp}$.

Comment: So you mean that both projections will be zero. Am i get it?

Comment: No, not necessarily.  You could have $v = u + w + w_1$, where $u \in U, w \in W, w_1 \in [U \oplus W]^{\perp}$, none of them zero.  Here $u$ and $w$ would be the projections of $v$ onto $U$ and $W$ respectively.

Comment: Maybe you are mistakenly thinking of $V$ as the union of $U, W$ and $[U \oplus W]^{\perp}$?

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much. Finally i proved. You great. :)

Comment: No problem.  If you're satisfied with my answer you can click "accept" on it so the question will be finished.